# How to stop execution of keyboard macro?

Tags: keyboard-macros

I mistakenly ran a keyboard macro with an Infinite Argument, which made the macro execute endlessly. Take the following example, which just inserts the character `a`:

```
C-x ( a C-x )
```

If I then run:

```
C-u 0 C-x e
```

in the `*scratch*` buffer, the newly defined keyboard macro will be executed over and over again.

I tried `C-g` several times, as well as `ESC-ESC-ESC`, but the execution did not stop, and I had to kill Emacs, as it was not responding. Is there any way to halt the execution of a macro without losing the Emacs session?

In case it makes a difference, the Emacs version I tried is 24.3.1.

Comment: When Emacs hangs it might be still possible to enter debugger by sending it a signal: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7565 - here's how to do it.

Comment: `C-g` should work (it just did for me). Try holding it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C-g` works for me, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). I did that with both Emacs 24.3 and a recent development snapshot for Emacs 25.

If you can give a recipe to reproduce what you see, starting from `emacs -Q`, consider sending a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: That's right, I tried it on my home computer (Emacs 24.3.50.1) and `C-g` worked fine. I will consider sending a bug report. Thanks!